# Enviar correos en laravel con mi dominio usuario@midominio.com

Tags: laravel, smtp, .env

Estoy tratando de enviar correos electrónicos con mi dominio user@ejemplo.com

Pero este lo siguen mandando a `mailtrap` no reconoce los cambios en el archivo `.env`.

local

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=3fdsfafdsfds24b916
MAIL_PASSWORD=7e4fdsfdsfw39a
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-repply@ejemplo.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

y para producción

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=contact@ejemplo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=unaContraseñá
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=contact@ejemplo.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Contact"
```

Otros datos:

- Servidor: `Dopled Ubuntu DigitalOcean`
- Dominio: `Hostinger`

Traté con otro dominio en `register`.

¿Alguna configuración que se me esté pasando?

¿Algo extra que deba configurar?

Comment: Intenta deteniendo el apache y volviendo a correr,  eso si los cambios los realizaste después de subido el proyecto, es decir subiste el proyecto con los datos de pruebas y después le cambiaste la configuración al archivo .env, otra opción, borrar la carpeta del servidor y subirla con las modificaciones para producción.

Comment: Detalle menor: ¿Droplet?

Comment: ¡@Alan solo reinicie el servidor y cambie la encriptación de tls a ssl y funciono!!